# Alias with > into /dev/clipboard not working

Tags: bash, cygwin, clipboard

In my cygwin's `.bashrc` I have the following two aliases:

```
alias dospath='cygpath -w `pwd`'
alias dospathcp='dospath > /dev/clipboard'
```

The first one is supposed to print the dos (or windows) path of the directory in which it is executed. This one works as expected.

The second alias is then supposed to redirect the output of `dospath` into `/dev/clipboard` so that I can paste it in windows applications. This one does not work. When I type `dospathcp` in bash, it just empties `/dev/clipboard` (and the clipbaord itself).

Comment: `dospathcp` works for me both in bash and zsh. I'm using Cygwin  2.830 64-Bit on Windows 7 Pro with MinTTy. Maybe try to put backticks around `dospath` in the `dospathcp` alias.

Comment: Does not work for me.  Though `echo $PWD > /dev/clipboard` works but `cygpath -w $PWD > /dev/clipboard` does NOT.  It's cygwin so I suspect its a bug :)

Comment: both `alias dospathcp='cygpath -w $PWD > /dev/clipboard'` and `cygpath -w $PWD > /dev/clipboard` work on my `CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 CC 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:39 i686 Cygwin`

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```bash
alias dospath='cygpath -w $PWD'
alias dospathcp='dospath > /dev/clipboard'
```

This produces following output in my CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 CC 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:39 i686 Cygwin

```bash
$ alias dospath='cygpath -w $PWD'
$ cd /home/somedir
$ dospath
W:\cygwin\home\somedir
$ cd /home/anotherdir
$ dospath
W:\cygwin\home\anotherdir
$ alias dospathcp='dospath > /dev/clipboard'
$ cd /home/somedir
$ dospathcp
$ cat /dev/clipboard
W:\cygwin\home\somedir
$ cd /home/anotherdir
$ dospathcp
$ cat /dev/clipboard
W:\cygwin\home\anotherdir
```

See http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html

> The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a
>   word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a
>   second time. This means that one may alias ls to "ls -F", for
>   instance, and Bash does not try to recursively expand the replacement
>   text.